# How to detect unsubscribe in Observer

Tags: observable, angular5, rxjs5

I wrap a http call to a new Observable, but I cannot detect if the subscription is cancelled:

```js
constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http) {
}


...


const observable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.http.post(url, body)
                .subscribe((p) => {
                    observer.next(p.json());
                    observer.complete();
                }, (err) => {
                    observer.error(err);
                    observer.complete();
                });
        });
const subscription = observable.subscribe((r) => { alert("result : "+r); }, (err) => { alert("error occured");}

subscription.unsubscribe(); // if user cancels the request
```

How can I detect in `Observable.create(...)` if the user cancels the subscription?  I would like to cancel the http post request when the outer Observable is cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually create `unsubscribe` function like:

```js
 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    let url = 'google.kz';

    const observable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      let cancel: Subscription = this.http.post(url, {})
        .subscribe((p) => {
          observer.next(p);
          observer.complete();
        }, (err) => {
          observer.error(err);
          observer.complete();
        });

      // Provide a way of canceling and disposing the internal observables
      return function unsubscribe() {
        cancel.unsubscribe();
      };
    });

    let unsc = observable.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    console.log('unsubscribe', unsc);

    unsc.unsubscribe();
  }
```

So, when you call `unsubscribe()` function of outer observable, inner observables unsubscribes too depending how it realized

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-detect-unsubscribe-in-observer)